# How to edit xml text value by Xpath with Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qtxml

Let's suppose i have an xml

```
<root>
  <element>
    <boo>Hello</boo>
  </element>
</root>
```

I can load this xml to `QDomDocument`, 
but i can't find a way to edit element by a query like (root/element/boo).

Is there any way to do such an action with Qt Xml?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to refer to an element by its path in Qt.

Comment: if you are using a high version of Qt, you can use Qt XML Patterns http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxmlpatterns-index.html

Comment: As stated in the documentation, Qt XML is no longer maintained. Beware that if you're going that route, you'll have to maintain Qt XML on your own.